# Error en el cursor al realizar una consulta en sqlite desde la carpeta assets cuando se elimina la aplicación y se vuelve a instalar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema cuando realizo una consulta a la base de datos SQLite desde la carpeta assets solo cuando desinstalo la aplicación y la vuelvo a instalar. Si es la primera vez que se instala la aplicación corre de manera normal sin ningún problema. En la lista de errores me muestra que el error se encuentra en el cursor pero no entiendo el motivo ya que cuando instalo la aplicación por primera vez no pasa esto. Cuando borro los datos de la carpeta data vuelve a funcionar todo de manera normal.

Adjunto el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ButtonRectangle button,button2;
    EditText view;
    private MyDatabase db;
    ListView listView;
    FloatingActionButton nuevaB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.view);
        db = new MyDatabase(MainActivity.this);
        button2 = (ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button = (ButtonRectangle) findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);
        nuevaB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatB);

        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(MyDatabase.DBNAME);

        //Si la base de datos no existe
        if(false == database.exists()) {
            db.getReadableDatabase();

            //Copiar db
            if (copyDatabase(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Base de datos creada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al crear la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        nuevaB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registro.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Buscar();
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.setText("");
                view.setEnabled(true);
                button.setEnabled(true);
                cargaralimento();
            }
        });

        cargaralimento();
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(MyDatabase.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = MyDatabase.DBLOCATION + MyDatabase.DBNAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void cargaralimento(){
        ArrayList<Alimento> item = new ArrayList<Alimento>();
        item = db.listarAlimentos();

        ArrayAdapter<Alimento> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Alimento>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Código del helper:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "dbTest.db";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.example.jinex.dbTest/databases/";
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();

        if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }

        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if(mDatabase != null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Alimento> listarAlimentos() throws SQLException {
        Alimento a = null;
        ArrayList<Alimento> item = new ArrayList<Alimento>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ALIMENTOS", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        try{
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
               a = new Alimento(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getDouble(4), cursor.getDouble(5), cursor.getDouble(6), cursor.getDouble(7), cursor.getDouble(8), cursor.getDouble(9), cursor.getDouble(10), cursor.getDouble(11), cursor.getDouble(12), cursor.getDouble(13), cursor.getDouble(14), cursor.getDouble(15), cursor.getDouble(16), cursor.getDouble(17), cursor.getDouble(18), cursor.getDouble(19), cursor.getDouble(20), cursor.getDouble(21));
                item.add(a);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error", e.toString());
        }

        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return item;
    }
}
```

Adjunto el error que sale:

> 04-19 18:25:43.365 18263-18263/com.example.jinex.dbTest
> E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 9 from a CursorWindow
> which has 635 rows, 9 columns.
>
> ```
> 04-19 18:25:43.367 18263-18263/com.example.jinex.dbTest D/error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 9 from
> ```
>
> CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
> accessing data from it.

La base de datos se encuentra en la carpeta assets y cuando se ejecuta la instalación se verifica si se encuentra en el celular. Si la encuentra no hace nada de lo contrario la copia.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es aquí, **estas definiendo indices fijos que seguramente no concuerdan con los valores de las columnas en la base de datos**:

```
a=new Alimento(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getDouble(4),cursor.getDouble(5),cursor.getDouble(6),cursor.getDouble(7),cursor.getDouble(8),cursor.getDouble(9),cursor.getDouble(10),cursor.getDouble(11),cursor.getDouble(12),cursor.getDouble(13),cursor.getDouble(14),cursor.getDouble(15),cursor.getDouble(16),cursor.getDouble(17),cursor.getDouble(18),cursor.getDouble(19),cursor.getDouble(20),cursor.getDouble(21));
```

te recomiendo que para evitar este tipo de error incluso por mantenimiento, en lugar de definir un indice:

```
cursor.getString(1)
```

definas el nombre del campo, esto te ahorrara muchos dolores de cabeza (lo digo por experiencia):

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nombre de campo")
```

Answer (score -1):

Pues al parecer tu base de datos solo cuenta con 9 columnas y tu estas intentando obtener el dato de 23 columnas.

```
a=new 
Alimento(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getDouble(4),cursor.getDouble(5),cursor.getDouble(6),cursor.getDouble(7),cursor.getDouble(8),cursor.getDouble(9),cursor.getDouble(10),cursor.getDouble(11),cursor.getDouble(12),cursor.getDouble(13),cursor.getDouble(14),cursor.getDouble(15),cursor.getDouble(16),cursor.getDouble(17),cursor.getDouble(18),cursor.getDouble(19),cursor.getDouble(20),cursor.getDouble(21));
```

aquí debes de modificar a:

```
 a=new Alimento(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getDouble(4),cursor.getDouble(5),cursor.getDouble(6),cursor.getDouble(7),cursor.getDouble(8);
```